# Python spyder debug freezes with circular importing

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

I have a problem with the debugger when some modules in my code call each other.
Practical example:

A file dog.py contains the following code:

```
import cat
print("Dog")
```

The file cat.py is the following:

```
import dog
print("Cat")
```

When I run dog.py (or cat.py) I don't have any problem and the program runs smoothly.
However, when I try to debug it, the whole spyder freezes and I have to kill the program.

Do you know how can I fix this? I would like to use this circular importing, as the modules use functions that are in the other modules.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> When I run dog.py (or cat.py) I don't have any problem and the program runs smoothly.

AFAICT that's mostly because a script is imported under the special name (`"__main__"`), while a module is imported under it's own name (here "dog" or "cat"). NB : the only difference between a script and a module is actually loaded - passed an argument to the python runtime (`python dog.py`) or imported from a script or any module with an `import` statement.

*(Actually circular imports issues are a bit more complicated than what I describe above, but I'll leave this to someone more knowledgeable.)*

To make a long story short: except for this particular use case (which is actually more of a side effect), Python does *not* support circular imports. If you have functions (classes, whatever) shared by other scripts or modules, put these functions in a different module. Or if you find out that two modules really depends on each other, you may just want to regroup them into a single module (or regroup the parts that depend on each other in a same module and everything else in one or more other modules).

Also: unless it's a trivial one-shot util or something that only depends on the stdlib, your script's content is often better reduced to a `main` function parsing command-line arguments / reading config files / whatever, importing the required modules and starting the effective process.

Comment: Thanks bruno. But how come the script doesn't work just when debugging? What is the difference?

Comment: @riccio777 I don't use spyder so I can't really tell, but I guess it's trying to import your modules for inspection (under it's real module name) and goes awry trying to handle the circular import.